# SQL select and date ranges (group by?)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

Hello? I have the following data by SQL select

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|   Name              DateStart                DateEnd      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| St Essai     2015-10-20 08:15:00      2015-10-20 10:15:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-20 10:30:00      2015-10-20 12:30:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-20 13:30:00      2015-10-20 15:30:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-20 15:45:00      2015-10-20 17:45:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-21 08:15:00      2015-10-21 10:15:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-21 10:30:00      2015-10-21 12:30:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-21 13:30:00      2015-10-21 15:30:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-21 15:45:00      2015-10-21 17:45:00 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

and as you see I have 4 rows for a day. I would like to have instead

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  Name              DateStart                DateEnd       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| St Essai     2015-10-20 08:15:00      2015-10-20 17:45:00 |
| St Essai     2015-10-21 08:15:00      2015-10-21 17:45:00 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The first row is `NAME`, second `DATE START`, last `DATE END`.

So Instead of 4 rows for a single day, only one regrouping the 4 dates.

Is it possible to have that ONLY if there is 4 rows (which represent a whole day).

Thank you very much !

Comment: I don't understand this. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. And please consider NOT SHOUTING at respondents.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME,
       MIN(DATE) AS date_from,
       MAX(DATE) AS date_to
FROM tablename
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks for ANSWERS but I need to order DAY PAR DAY. Your solutions will combine data even if the day is a week later which is bad for what I'm doing (schedules for teachers)

Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Group by name and take min amd max

```
select NAME, min(DATE_START), max(DATE_END) from thetable group by NAME, date(DATE_START)
```

Comment: Thanks for ANSWERS but I need to order DAY PAR DAY. Your solutions will combine data even if the day is a week later which is bad for what I'm doing (schedules for teachers)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select name,min(date) as date_from, max(date) as date_to from table
group by name
```

Comment: Thanks for ANSWERS but I need to order DAY PAR DAY. Your solutions will combine data even if the day is a week later which is bad for what I'm doing (schedules for teachers)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56b24f/1) you go. I have created a table that should look like yours, and complicated the data a bit just to test it better. The ideea is to find for each day the min and max hours and join them to a single row.

```
select minTable.minhour , maxTable.maxhour, maxTable.name
from (select  min(startdate) as minhour, date(startdate) as aday, name from ATable
group by aday, name) minTable 
join 
(select  max(enddate) as maxhour, date(enddate) as aday , name from ATable
group by aday, name) maxTable
on minTable.aday = maxTable.aday and minTable.name = maxTable.name
```

or more simple...

```
select  min(startdate) , max(enddate), name from ATable
group by date(startdate), name
```

Comment: My datable is a bit complicated : "SELECT tu.identifier, t.acronym, a.start, a.end FROM activities a JOIN audiences aud ON aud.id = audience_id JOIN teaching_units tu ON tu.id = teaching_unit_id JOIN teachers t ON t.id = a.teacher_id WHERE aud.type='Class' ORDER BY a.start ASC" this is how I get my data atm. How to combine this and your solution ? Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `date(datestart)` in your group by:

```
select name,
       min(datestart) as  datestart,
       max(dateend) as  dateend
   from mytable
   group by name,date(datestart);
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca3b/4/0)